# Commercially available reference to spectral colors?

Tags: visible-light

Since every computer display uses RGB color space, it cannot display most actually spectral colors. Mostly, even their primary colors are far from spectral, for example, sRGB's green.

I'd like to see the actual spectral colors as many as possible. Is there any commercially available reference to them?

**EDIT:** The reference must: 1) consist of many but discrete colors, 2) be available everywhere and anytime, and 3) specify the wavelength of each color.

Comment: It sounds like you need to use the information in this question ; [Visible Light Spectrum to Color Space](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/18557/visible-light-spectrum-to-color-space?rq=1).

Comment: @StephenG Don't tell me I need to stimulate my own pigments directly... An array of LED would be enough.

Comment: It's not clear what your actual question is. If you want to see the actual spectral colors, why not just look at a solar spectrum projected onto a white surface? Do you want to know the wavelength of a given spectral color?

Comment: @PM2Ring That will only work at daytime; see the edit.

Comment: Many wide color space monitors are available today along with precise color calibration systems. No need to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: @safesphere I don't think a wide-color space monitor displays sufficiently spectral colors, especially at cyan regions.

Comment: Sufficiently for which purpose or application?

Comment: @safesphere Just for demonstration of spectral colors.

Comment: I see. Thanks for the clarification. Perhaps a quartz incandescent lamp with a corrective filter and a prism splitting the colors? However, you need a product, not a DIY idea.

Comment: @safesphere Yes, exactly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For round-the-clock spectral goodnes either go for a cheap full spectum source like an incandescent lamp plus a cheap  , usually grating- based, spectroscope with markings; or heavily invest in a full spectrum tunable laser system (they usually tune from 580 to 1xxxnm but an additional frequency doubling crystal will then get you the blues too.