# How do I translate from CIE xyY color space to combinations of monochromatic wavelengths

Tags: visible-light, vision

Let's say I have a chromaticity point, on the CIE xyY color space that falls within the real colors. (Like y:0.1, x:0.4 Y:1 -- magenta)[1]

I also know that humans can perceive the same color, when viewing different distributions of light as long as the wavelengths in the distribution result in the same tristimulus values in the eye[2]

Using the CIE color matching functions, can I determine all the combinations of monochromatic wavelengths that when combined, will appear as the color CIExyY 0.1, 0.4 to most people?

In other words, if I have some monochromatic lasers of various colors sitting around, how can I determine which ones I can combine (at various intensities) to replicate colors as specified in CIExyY form.

**Adding a bounty and this follow up:
Fundamentally, I don't understand how to use CIE color information as a recipe for reproducing those colors with my own hypothetical display device.**

[1]http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CIE_1931_color_space#/media/File:CIE1931xy_blank.svg
[2]http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metamerism_(color)

Comment: Related - http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/15563/conversion-formula-from-spectrophotometer-readings-to-any-standard-color-space-p/16809#16809

Comment: This should be condensed into a proper stack exchange answer but until that happens, this blog post covers precisely this question. https://www.fourmilab.ch/documents/specrend/